# Django installation in windows command line

Tags: python, windows, django

I've done below command in command line in windows:

```
python.exe setup.py install
```

It was running then came up with this error:

```
error: invalid command 'install_lib' (no class 'install_lib' in module 'distutil
s.command.install_lib')
```

Can anyone pinpoint what it is?

Comment: `<wild guess>` Sounds like your `distutils` is broken. How did you install Python?`</wild guess>`.

Comment: I installed python using windows installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install [setuptools for windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) and then run the command.

Comment: I installed setuptools but it's not working still I can't do import django

Comment: Did you [install django](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#django) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11) installed. You can easily install it with the `ez_setup.py`. After you did that, I recommend you to install `pip` with `easy_install pip` (easy_install comes with setuptools), then installing `django` is just: `pip install django`.